# AttributeError: 'ModelName' object has no attribute 'get' if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to get a list of Scripts

I'm not sure why this error is django throwing however, Can anybody identify if there's something is wrong.

Model

```
class Script(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    script = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializer

```
class ScriptSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    script = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
```

view;

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def scripts(request):
    scripts = Script.objects.all()
    serializer = ScriptSerializer(scripts, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

but when I call this view, I get this error

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/seo/scripts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\folder\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\folder\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "E:\folder\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:
AttributeError: 'Script' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have also seen answers related to that issue in Stackoverflow but not able to reproduce the solution. And also this approach is not new to me, I have been using this type of functions all over the project. But I'm surprised now why it's happening.

Edit:
Imports

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import ScriptSerializer
from .models import Script
```

urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views as views

app_name = "seo"

urlpatterns = [
    path('scripts', views.Script, name='scripts'),
]
```

Comment: Your view is returning a `Script` object instead of a `Response` object. It's not apparent from the code you've shared where this is happening - maybe show us the rest of the views file, including the imports. Where is `Response` being imported from? Also show us the URL definition for this view.

Comment: @solarissmoke Please see the edit , I have included the imports

Comment: I still can't see where the issue is from your code. Do you have any custom middleware installed?

Comment: No but it's referring to 
`'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',` according to error, and this was by default added while the project was created

Comment: That's just where the error is happening - the response object has been messed up before that point. There's something else going on in your code that you've not included in the question.

Comment: There's your problem - `views.Script` in your URLs should be `views.scripts`. You have imported the model class instead of the view function.

Comment: Yeah... got it , my bad , that was just a cheesy mistake , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is in naming collision. Take a closer look to this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def scripts(request):
    scripts = Script.objects.all()
    serializer = ScriptSerializer(scripts, many=True)
```

The function named `scripts` and then this name reassigned with `scripts = Script.objects.all()`. This may lead to really unexpected behaviours

So try to rename your local variable. I.e.:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def scripts(request):
    script_items = Script.objects.all()
```

**UPD** after `urls.py` added:

It should point to the function view i.o. model:

```
path('scripts', views.scripts, name='scripts'),
```

Comment: It's not working I have already tried this naming the list to `qs` or `script_items `

Comment: @Oddball, add also your `urls.py` please where this endpoint is defined

Comment: Please check the edit I have added the urls.py

Comment: Yes that was the prob. as  
solarissmoke also has described , Thanks for the effort thu